# Function doesn't show images

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script

```
function add(){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = document.getElementById(counter).files[0].tmp_name;
    var src = document.getElementById('asd');
    src.appendChild(img);
}
```

The function is called after a selection from a file input on an HTML. I use the `tmp_name` of the selected to create a thumbnail of the selection, but instead it shows an error with both `tmp_name` and `name`, but if I change the `img.src`, for example, to `"https://duckduckgo.com/assets/icons/meta/DDG-icon_256x256.png"`, it shows the link image after the selection. How can I get the path of the image or just add its thumbnail after selected from a mobile browser?

Comment: Where is counter defined? What error are you receiving? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: When you say you change the source to the online image, do you mean you run it through the function like that?  Or you just manually set the source?

Comment: Can this example help you? https://jsfiddle.net/xvnbe0d7/

Comment: The counter is a global variable, above that function. No error, the image shows like this http://imgur.com/cHjhZ2z and this is my html http://imgur.com/a/Tg364.

Comment: Nicklas, It Worked, Thanks :D